# Responsive background-image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Alright, seems like a simple problem but I can't find a proper solution. I need responsive/fluid images so they scale relative to the viewport size, but I also need them to be loaded with css using the background property so I can selectively load different versions with media queries. How do I achieve both?

edit:

Here is the code example. Currently the image is not showing, I assume because there is no fixed width or height established in the parent element (beyond width: 100%). The parent element needs to be 100% width though too, to keep it scaling responsively. The image is 400px x 400px.

HTML

```
<div class="why-us"></div>
```

CSS

```
.why-us {
  background: url(../lemonsevens/img/img_2x.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Just any generic example works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quiet sure what you want, but I guess that is something like this:

Snippet edited based on OP comment.

```css
.bg-img {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/400x400) no-repeat 0 0 / 100% auto;
  height: 400px;
}

/*added based on OP comments*/

@media (max-width : 480px){
  .bg-img {
    background-size:contain
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a background image to cover the entire page. It's just a 400px x 400px image.

Comment: That's closer, but now it is stretching the entire viewport.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle of your work? so i can help you better?

Comment: Okay, here is a rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtkmjnmg/                 It is basically working as I want it now, except I would like the image to decrease in size as the screen width decreases. Because it is centered, that doesn't happen until the viewport is very small. I suppose it may be better to just use Foundation or something to use columns?

Comment: I think it is good, I would change the padding for the section on small viewports or instead having `100% auto` I would change for `contain` again for small viewports, like `max-width: 480px`. Let me know if you want me to add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

example 
i have

```
<div id="image"> </div>
```

css class

```
#image{
 background:url("src_for_my_image");
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I added a code snippet to my OP. With your solution, my image does not show.